# Omit "@" and "style" from Style Parent Attribute?

Tags: android, android-styles

The [Style Resource documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html) shows the syntax of the `parent` attribute of a `style` definition as:

```
parent="@[package:]style/style_to_inherit"
```

The resource parser is actually more tolerant.  The "@" and "style" are both optional.  This is understandable given that the value must be a reference to a style.  Each of the following forms is accepted and seem to be equivalent.

```
<resources>

    <style name="ThemeA" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo"/>
    <style name="ThemeB" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo"/>
    <style name="ThemeC" parent="android:Theme.Holo"/> <!-- auto completion supported -->

    <style name="ThemeD" parent="@style/ThemeA"/>
    <style name="ThemeE" parent="style/ThemeA"/>
    <style name="ThemeF" parent="ThemeA"/> <!-- auto completion supported -->

</resources>
```

Android Studio 1.3 only applies auto-completion to the forms that do not contain "@" and "style", making their use more convenient.  Is there any reason why "@" and "style" should not always be omitted from a `parent` declaration?